# Text only web browser for OS X

Tags: macos, browser

I'm looking for a text only web browser for OS X. I don't want a browser that runs in terminal like `links`. I want one that has a GUI but just doesn't display images. Is there one like that, or is there a browser for OS X that can be configured to be like that?

Comment: Shouldn't `links` be `lynx`? (Sort of the web browser equivalent of `pine`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser) ). [EDIT] Nm. I see they're both valid browsers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/fx/)

1. Open Preferences
2. Go to "Content"
3. Uncheck the box that says "Load images automatically"

### [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/)

1. Open Preferences
2. Go to "Appearance"
3. Uncheck the box that says "Display images when the page opens."

### [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)

1. Open Preferences
2. Go to "Under the Hood"
3. Click "Content Settings" under "Privacy"
4. Click "Do not show any images"

### [Opera](http://opera.com)

1. Open Preferences
2. Go to "Webpages"
3. Choose "No Images" under "Images"

Comment: Come on, 11 upvotes?

Comment: @Lri Why? Is this a bad thing?

Comment: Because even though the question is somewhat ambiguous, it seems like the OP is looking for a GUI-equivalent of Lynx or Links.

Comment: @Lri: I don't think that the OP was necessarily specifying that. They were just asking for a browser that could be used without images, or could be configured to do so.

Comment: It kind of works, but not really. There is still a space where the images are supposed to appear.

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for something similar and I'm not satisfied with the accepted answer.

Lynxlet seems to be a decent option:

http://habilis.net/lynxlet/

Comment: lynxlet is not a web browser itself - it's only a launcher for lynx

Answer (score 0):

The excellent Firefox add-on "Web Developer" has (among countless options designed to assist web developers) an option to "Disable Images," which turns Firefox into a fully functional but text-only web browser!!! You can get more information and download the add-on here: http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer . It's currently being used by more than 700,000 people, and has almost entirely positive reviews.

Once Web Developer is installed, to disable images simply go to the Firefox Menu and select Tools --> Web Developer Extension --> Images --> Disable Images --> Disable All Images.

CRUCIAL NOTE! — the "Web Developer" add-on is DIFFERENT from Firefox's built in "Web Developer" tool, which will also appear in the "Tools" menu! The "Web Developer" add-on will appear in the "Tools" menu as "Web Developer Extension," while Firefox's built-in "Web Developer" tool will appear in the "Tools" menu as simply "Web Developer" (WITHOUT the word "Extension")

Enyoy!